# Querying History Object in update trigger, not showing the new History Object record?

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger, field-history

I have a custom object (TestObject1__c) wherein I am tracking some field changes. I also have related list under this object (TestObject1__History). The problem is the trigger I created isn't querying the new record I change in TestObject1__History.

What I mean is, if I have 10 records in particular ParentId of TestObject1__History. But if I update the field that I am tracking, it will only query the 10 records in TestObject1__History, not 11. It's not working in both before and after trigger either. Why is that?

```
public class TestObject1Class {

    public static void testMet(List<TestObject1__c> obs) {
        List<TestObject1__History> lHis = [SELECT Id, Field, DataType, NewValue, OldValue, ParentId, CreatedDate FROM TestObject1__History];
        // it will only query the TestObject1__History before update happens. 
        System.debug('lHis size: ' + lHis.size());
        
        Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(TestObject1__c parent :obs){
            parentIds.add(parent.Id);
        }
                
        for(TestObject1__History ob : [SELECT Id, Field, DataType, NewValue, OldValue, ParentId, CreatedDate FROM TestObject1__History WHERE ParentId IN :parentIds]) {
            System.debug('ob ' + ob);
        }
    }
}


trigger TestObject1Trigger on TestObject1__c (after insert, before insert, after update, before update) {
    
    if(trigger.isAfter) {  
        if(trigger.isUpdate) {
            TestObject1Class.testMet(trigger.new);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

History records are not calculated until the end of the transaction, so the earliest you can see those new entries would be in asynchronous code that runs after the transaction that caused the changes to be fully completed and committed. Options include using a future method, a queueable class, a CDC (Change Data Capture) trigger, etc. You can also use the values in `Trigger.old` and `Trigger.new` to see which field values have changed.